# HTML code allowing users to one click join a specific gameserver

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

exactly how the title is mentioned, do any of you know how to implement the html code to allow users on a website to join a Halo:Combat Evolved gameserver by clicking a link once or even any type of game at that matter?

I know how to do this with a ts3server:

```
<a href="ts3server://IP?port=#">TS3</a>
```

but cannot figure out how it would work for a halo gameserver...Any help would be much appreciated!

What I've tried and does not work:

```
<a href="halo://IP?port=#">Halo</a>
<a href="halo://IP:PORT">Halo</a>
```

as well as a few others...

Comment: Would WebSockets need to be created/established for this specific case?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware this isn't possible. I know that TS3 and Skype have this ability but that is built into the browser/software. It's not possible to just put game/software://IP:Port and be guaranteed that it will work. Try google for any other solutions or look at the code of sites that have this function.

Comment: @canon, wouldn't it be possible to simply locate a specific .exe file on a users computer and automatically open it up in relation to an IP and Port that the game has a gameserver in?  All based on a single click on the site?

Comment: @Robbo, I have tried to google the shiznit out of this particular scenario and couldn't find any significant results...

Comment: So in order for this to work, I'd have to create/register a uri schema?  Let's say establish the name of it as 'example' than once finished with that, the 'example' would replace 'ts3server' ?

Comment: why would it only work on my computer and not others if they click the link? Or am I misunderstanding something...

Comment: I still don't fully understand...So, what I think your saying is that I'd have to create an application directly for my site - in which users of my site have to download - once they download it, they can either one click launch a game server from that application or from the site then?